# Using launchd to run script once a day when logged in

Tags: script, launchd, cron, macos

I'm in the situation where I would like to run a script **only once** per day when I open my MacBook.

I guess I could have the script note the date it was last run, and have it reject when run on the noted day.. however I was hoping launchd had some fancy mechanics to avoid this!

After googling a bit about crontab and offline schedules, I learned about anacron which unfortunately isn't available on macOS -- however they all recommended launchd instead.

TL;DR: say I have a script I want to run **only once** a day. I can schedule it for 6, 8 or 10 in the morning, however there is no guarantee that I will have my laptop open (or even booted into macOS) at this time. What's the trick for scheduling an event that will happen once in a certain timespan, despite it not being online for all of it?

Comment: As far as I know it is like any other launchd job only that it is now moved to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` because it is active when the user is logged in instead of system-wide.

Comment: I thought launchd would take care of this automatically if you use a `StartInterval` or `StartCalendarInterval` key in the .plist.

Comment: @GordonDavisson almost, but note that the automatic rescheduling behavior depends and the computer being *asleep* (not off) when the actual schedule is missed. If we read the OP literally, he or she is like me and turns the Mac off for the night, instead of putting it to sleep. I need a solution for this too.